# Re-render navbar in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a problem when building app with angular2.
I define `routes` in two array:

appRoutes.ts

```
var beforeLogin = [
        { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true },
        { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: '/**', name: ' ', redirectTo: ['Home'] }
    ],
    afterLogin = [
        { path: '/about', name: 'About', component: AboutComponent, useAsDefault: true },
        { path: '/**', name: ' ', redirectTo: ['About'] }
    ];
```

App.ts: register `routes` in `RouterConfig`, and register `NavbarComponent` as `derective`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',
    templateUrl: './src/app/app.html',
    directives: [RouterOutlet, NavbarComponent],
    pipes: [TranslatePipe]
})

@RouteConfig(APP_ROUTES) //register routes config
```

navbar.ts:

```
export class NavbarComponent {
    private routeList: RouteDefinition[];

    constructor() {
        this.routeList = APP_ROUTES;
        this.isLogin = Security.getLogin();
    }

    logout() { 
        this.updateNavbar();    
    }

    updateNavbar() {

    }
}
```

navbar.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li *ngFor="#route of routeList"><a [routerLink]="[route.name]">{{route.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

I wants `navbar` can re-render when login/logout app. After login can't load route in `beforeLogin` routes(redirect to `Home`, etc...), and vice versa
`beforeLogin`: show in `navbar` when load app.
`afterLogin`: show in `navbar` after login.

Any idea for me, thanks.